# When does prime elements remain prime in certain integral extension

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $\bar R$ denote its integral closure in the fraction field (i.e. normalization). If $p\in R$ is a prime element in $R$, then does $p$ remain prime in $\bar R$ also ?

If this is not true in general, then what if we also assume $R$ is Noetherian ?

By a prime element in an integral domain $R$, I mean a non-zero non unit $p\in R$ such that $p |ab $ for some $a,b \in R$ implies $p|a$ or $p|b$ i.e. if $pR$ is a prime ideal in $R$ . I can see that $p$ still remains a non-unit in $\bar R$ , but I'm unable to say anything about the ideal $p\bar R$.

UPDATE : The claim is true for any Noetherian domain. This is Lemma 4.7 in ; On finite generation of $R$-subalgebras of $R[X]$ , Amartya K. Dutta; Nobuharu Onoda; Journal of Algebra 320 (2008) 57- 80. On finite generation of R-subalgebras of R[X] - ScienceDirect
https://www.sciencedirect.com › pii

Comment: No, even if $R$ is assumed to be Noetherian. For an example, let $k$ be a field and set $R = k[t^2 - 1, t(t^2 - 1)]$. Then $p = t^2 - 1$ is a prime element since $R/pR = k$ is an integral domain. However, the normalization $\overline R \cong k[t]$ and $p = (t - 1)(t + 1)$ there. This example comes from geometry: $R$ here is the coordinate ring of a nodal cubic, and the prime element $p$ corresponds to the node at the origin. When you normalize, the node splits off into two points, and so the pullback of this prime element factors into two smaller things.

Comment: @RaymondCheng: your element $p$ is not prime (but it is irreducible). The ring is $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$, so if $p = x$ then the quotient is $k[y]/(y^2)$, not $k$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: Great, yes: $R/p$ still has the class represented by $t(t^2 - 1)$. Thanks (:

Answer (score 7):

This is true when $R$ is reasonable. The properties that I use are:

1. $R$ is Noetherian;
2. $\tilde R$ is Noetherian;
3. $\tilde R$ is catenary and equidimensional (i.e. every maximal chain $0 = \mathfrak q_0 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq \mathfrak q_d$ of prime ideals in $\tilde R$ has the same length).

For example, these are all satisfied if $R$ is of finite type over a field or over $\mathbb Z$. It might be possible to weaken some of these hypotheses.

**Lemma.** Let $f\colon R \to S$ be an integral ring map, let $\mathfrak q \subseteq S$ be a prime, and let $\mathfrak p = f^{-1}(\mathfrak q)$. Then
$$\dim R/\mathfrak p = \dim S/\mathfrak q.$$

*Proof.* This is poset-theoretic, using only the going up theorem for integral maps [AM, Thm. 5.11]. Indeed, the going up theorem implies that a chain $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak p_1 \subsetneq \ldots$ of primes of $R$ containing $\mathfrak p$ can be lifted to some chain $\mathfrak q = \mathfrak q_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak q_1 \subsetneq \ldots$ of $S$, whence $\dim S/\mathfrak q \geq \dim R/\mathfrak p$.

Conversely, if $\mathfrak q_1 \subseteq \mathfrak q_2$ are primes of $S$ with $f^{-1}(\mathfrak q_1) = f^{-1}(\mathfrak q_2) = \mathfrak p$, then we must have $\mathfrak q_1 = \mathfrak q_2$. Indeed, they correspond to primes in the integral ring map $\kappa(\mathfrak p) \to S \otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak p)$, and there are no inclusions between prime ideals of $S \otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak p)$ [[Tag 00GS](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00GS)(3)]. Hence, the inverse image of a chain $\mathfrak q = \mathfrak q_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak q_1 \subsetneq \ldots$ of primes of $S$ containing $\mathfrak q$ is a *strict* chain $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak p_1 \subsetneq \ldots$ of primes of $R$ containing $\mathfrak p$, whence $\dim R/\mathfrak p \geq \dim S/\mathfrak q$. $\square$

**Remark.** In the proof below, we want to relate the heights of $\mathfrak q$ and $\mathfrak p$ as in the lemma. We can do this under assumption (3), for this forces $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p) = \dim R - \dim R/\mathfrak p$ (and similarly for $\mathfrak q$).

> > **Proposition.** Let $R$ be a domain satisfying properties (1)-(3) above. If $p \in R$ is a prime element, then $p$ is a prime element in $\tilde R$.

*Proof.* By assumption, $\mathfrak p = (p)$ is a prime ideal. By Krull's Hauptidealsatz [AM, Cor. 11.17], this implies that $\mathfrak p$ has height $1$, i.e. $R_\mathfrak p$ is a $1$-dimensional domain. Since its maximal ideal $\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p$ is principal, we conclude that $R_\mathfrak p$ is a DVR [AM, Prop. 9.2] with uniformiser $p$; in particular $R_\mathfrak p$ is normal.

On the other hand, normalisation commutes with localisation [AM, Prop. 5.12]. Thus,
$$(\tilde R)_\mathfrak p = (R_\mathfrak p)^\sim = R_\mathfrak p,$$
since $R_\mathfrak p$ is normal. That is, the natural map $R \to \tilde R$ becomes an isomorphism when tensoring with $R_\mathfrak p$, hence also when tensoring with $\kappa(\mathfrak p) = R_\mathfrak p/\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p$. The primes of $\tilde R \otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak p)$ are the primes of $\tilde R$ lying over $\mathfrak p$ [AM, Exc. 3.21(iv)], so we conclude that there is a unique such prime $\mathfrak q$. Note that $\mathfrak q$ is minimal over $\mathfrak p\tilde R$, hence has height $1$ by Krull's Hauptidealsatz.

If $\mathfrak r \subseteq \tilde R$ is another height $1$ prime, then $p \not\in \mathfrak r$. Indeed, if $p \in \mathfrak r$, then $\mathfrak p' = \mathfrak r \cap R$ contains $\mathfrak p$. Applying the lemma and the remark above, we conclude that $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p') = \operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak r) = 1$. Hence $\mathfrak p' = \mathfrak p$ since $\mathfrak p \subseteq \mathfrak p'$ and both have height $1$.

Hence, for a height $1$ prime $\mathfrak r \subseteq \tilde R$, we have
$$v_{\mathfrak r}(p) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1, & \mathfrak r = \mathfrak q,\\ 0, & \mathfrak r \neq \mathfrak q, \end{array}\right.$$
since $p$ is a uniformiser of the DVR $\tilde R_\mathfrak q \cong R_\mathfrak p$. If $q \in \mathfrak q$, then $v_\mathfrak r(q) \geq v_\mathfrak r(p)$ for all height $1$ primes $\mathfrak r \subseteq \tilde R$. Hence, $\frac{q}{p} \in \tilde R$ [Eis, Cor. 11.4], which shows that $\mathfrak q \subseteq (p)$. The reverse inclusion follows since $\mathfrak q \cap R = \mathfrak p$, hence $(p) = \mathfrak q$ is prime. $\square$

**Remark.** In geometric language, we proved:

1. There is a unique irreducible divisor $V(\mathfrak q) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} \tilde R$ dominating the irreducible divisor $V(\mathfrak p) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} R$;
2. The locus $V(p) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} \tilde R$ does not split off a new component of higher codimension;
3. The uniformiser $p$ for the divisor $V(\mathfrak p) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} R$ remains a uniformiser for $V(\mathfrak q) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} \tilde R$ (there is no ramification).

---

**References.**

[AM] Atiyah, M.F.; Macdonald, I.G., *Introduction to commutative algebra*. Addison-Wesley Publishing Company (1969). [ZBL0175.03601](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0175.03601).

[Eis] Eisenbud, D., *Commutative algebra with a view toward algebraic geometry*. Graduate Texts in Mathematics **150**, Springer-Verlag (1995). [ZBL0819.13001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0819.13001).

Comment: OK. What does it mean for a ring to be Japanese?  Gerhard "Enquiring Mind Seeking Knowledge, Arigato" Paseman, 2018.01.28.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: it [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_ring) that for every finite extension $K = \operatorname{Frac} R \to L$, the integral closure of $R$ in $L$ is finite over $R$. We only need the case $K = L$.

Comment: Dear Remi, I'm sorry but  in line 16 I don't understand to what inclusion of prime ideals  in  $R_{\mathfrak p'}$ you apply the going-up theorem  for the morphism $R_{\mathfrak p'} \to (\tilde R)_{\mathfrak p'}$

Comment: For the kinds of rings you described, do you think for any prime ideal $P$ in $R$, $P\tilde R$ is prime in $\tilde R$ also ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I wanted to do the following: if $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p') > 1$, then there is a chain $0 \subsetneq \mathfrak p'' \subsetneq \mathfrak p'$. Applying going up gives a chain of length at least $2$ in $(\tilde R)_{\mathfrak p'}$. But I just realised that this is not necessarily contained in $\mathfrak r$, so the argument indeed seems to have a gap. I'm not sure how to fix it at this moment; I hope it doesn't break the argument.

Comment: @misao: there are many examples if $\mathfrak p$ is not principal, even if it still has height $1$. For example, consider the resolution of the nodal or cuspidal cubic. (See also Raymond's comment above.)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I'm fairly certain my current argument should fix it (at the expense of somewhat strengthening the hypotheses).

Comment: Yes, your new answer convinces me [but I can't upvote you again :-)]. Do you know an example of  a Noetherian domain $R$  and  a prime $\mathfrak P                                                             \subset \tilde R$ whose height in $\tilde R $ is not the same as the height of $\mathfrak P\cap R$ in $R$? Or even an example in the situation $R\subset S$ where $S$ is just supposed to be a domain  integral over $R$, but not necessarily its integral closure?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I have thought about this, but so far this has been unsuccessful. Most non-equidimensional domains I can think of are a localisation of some finite type domain, so height behaves the same as in the finite type case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, Remi, and sorry for bothering you so much. The subject seems to be unexpectedly and frustratingly hard.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I have an answer to your question about height.  Could you post it as a regular question?

Comment: @Neil: [With pleasure!](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292514/450)

Comment: I just wanted to comment that recently I have found out that the assertion of the question I was making is correct if $R$ is a Noetherian domain. This is Lemma 4.7 in ; On finite generation of $R$-subalgebras of $R[X]$ , Amartya K. Dutta; Nobuharu Onoda; Journal of Algebra 320 (2008) 57- 80. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869308001051/pdf%3Fmd5%3D4cc9aaf852328c3c5668dad6b0194571%26pid%3D1-s2.0-S0021869308001051-main.pdf%26_valck%3D1&ved=2ahUKEwiP-YzS7pTbAhWBNY8KHYMEB6QQFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw3EdHuJMLHuL44cAXmMNl7p

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, please, could you help me with my following question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353057/prime-irreducible-elements-in-certain-integral-ring-extensions?noredirect=1&lq=1, which is a variation/generalization of the above question. Thank you.